# How can I say that .. Some toilets

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases

There is / there are
Some ,any + plural
e.g 
there are some pictures in our room
There aren't any pictures in our room
what about toilets
How can I say toilets with [positive][negative]

Comment: Isn't it unusual to use plural with toilet, and to use "in our room"? Usually you would (in a hotel) have one toilet with your room - but not in your room. But maybe I don't understand the context.

Comment: In general I mean 
Let me give you for example 
There are some toilets in our school
Is this sentence correct?

Answer (score 1):

Just in the same way:

> There is a toilet
>
> There are toilets
>
> There are some toilets
>
> There aren't any toilets
>
> There are no toilets

All are valid

Edit: Re the OP's comment, both of the following are valid:

> There are some toilets in our school
>
> There are toilets in our school

The latter would be the more common usage in my experience, but there is no real difference in meaning.